# Is c++ singleton need memory barrier while using mutex?

Tags: c++, memory-barriers, stdmutex

I have known that mutex can also bring the effect as memory barrier from here: [Can mutex replace memory barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738028/can-mutex-replace-memory-barriers), but I always see there is an memory barrier using in c++ singleton example as below, is the memory barrier unnecessary?

```
Singleton* Singleton::getInstance() {
     Singleton* tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
     std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);        
     if (tmp == nullptr) {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);               // using mutex here
         tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
         if (tmp == nullptr) {
             tmp = new Singleton;
             assert(tmp != nullptr);    
             std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release); // using memory barrier here
             m_instance.store(tmp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
         }
     }
     return tmp;
 }
```

Comment: You don't need all that stuff at all, just do as described in Scott Meyer's _C++ Singleton Pattern_ (the dupe). It's lazy evaluated, and already comes with thread safety guaranteed..

Comment: thanks, but I also want to figure out whether the memory barrier is necessary or not @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Pthread_mutexes, which are often used as the underpinning for C++ locks, define lock and unlock operations as address space wide barriers; so in that instance, you would not require the fences.  Does your implementation of std::lock_guard document that guarantee?   The standard (sic) seems uncharacteristically mute on the subject.

Comment: You will benefit more from reading on how memory models work than asking about particular examples. That said, it usually isn't suggested to touch any atomics other than sequential consistent.

Comment: _@woder_ _"but I also want to figure out whether the memory barrier is necessary or not"_ As mentioned, it's not needed. Scott Meyer's Singleton Pattern doesn't need any locks or barriers. But well, @Nathan decided to reopen and unduplicate your question, despiete all the answers you wanted/needed are already there IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `Scott Meyer's Singleton Pattern` uses static to initialize object is good and simple, but problems come when there are a specify initialize order request among different single instances, and there are another solution using using pthread_once to create single instance , whatever, I am not looking for how to create a single instance but just wondering the mutex and memory barrier

Comment: @mevets thanks for your comment, it is on the point

Comment: Is there a reason to use two operations (`std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
             m_instance.store(tmp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
`) instead of a release store?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++11, you do not need to program your own protection.

As also referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), all the needed stuff is already part of C++11. Copied from there:

> For the singleton pattern, double-checked locking is not needed:

> If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.
> — § 6.7 [stmt.dcl] p4

```
Singleton& GetInstance() {
  static Singleton s;
  return s;
}
```

The implementation will provide a memory barrier or whatever to protect your concurrent access. So keep it simple as given in the example!

Comment: `Scott Meyer's Singleton Pattern` uses static to initialize object is good and simple, but problems come when there are a specify initialize order request among different single instances, and there are another solution using using pthread_once to create single instance , whatever, I am not looking for how to create a single instance but just wondering the mutex and memory barrier, thanks for your answer